# Does an each element of sum of bounded function is bounded?

Tags: summation, normed-spaces, bounded-variation, upper-lower-bounds

I have a sum of two element as following:

$$e_i=x_{i-1}-x_i$$

I know that $e_i \in L_{\infty}$ so it is bounded. Is it true then that $x_i$ and $x_{i-1}$ are also in $L_{\infty}$ (bounded)?

Comment: does i ranges over whole numbers?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Does $i$ ranges from $0$ to infinity?

Comment: Basically, it is a distance error ($e_i$) between a vehicles (vehicle platoon). So, yes $i$ can go to infinity.

Comment: You can use induction and $x_i = x_{i-1} - e_i$ to show that $x_i$ is bounded.

Comment: Hmm.. I do not see how to prove that with induction.

Comment: Sum of bounded function is bounded therefore if $x_{i-1}$ is bounded then $x_i = x_{i-1}-e_i$ is bounded so all you have to prove is that $x_1$ is bounded.